# Scraping data from Wikipedia using Htmlagilitypack

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, web-scraping, html-agility-pack

I am trying to scrape data from a table on the Wikipedia website and so far I have managed to find the nodes that I need to reference. There are a large number of entries in the table on Wikipedia, however, when I run the app I only get twelve results and they are all identical. All results returned are duplicates of the first entry in the table.

Any ideas on how to fix?

```
protected async override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
    string htmlPage = "";
    {
        htmlPage = await client.GetStringAsync("http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Games_with_Gold_games");
    }

HtmlDocument htmlDocument = new HtmlDocument();
htmlDocument.LoadHtml(htmlPage);

foreach (var div in htmlDocument.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(".//h2"))
{
    GameHistory newGameHistory = new GameHistory();
    newGameHistory.historyTitle = div.SelectSingleNode("//i//a").InnerText.Trim();
    newGameHistory.historyAdded = div.SelectSingleNode("//span[starts-with(@style, 'white')]").InnerText.Trim();
    newGameHistory.historyRemoved = div.SelectSingleNode("(//span[starts-with(@style, 'white')])[2]").InnerText.Trim();
    gameHistory.Add(newGameHistory);
    }
lstGameHistory.ItemsSource = gameHistory;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your XPath is not completely right...

```
foreach (var div in htmlDocument.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(".//h2"))
{
    GameHistory newGameHistory = new GameHistory();
    newGameHistory.historyTitle = div.SelectSingleNode("//i//a").InnerText.Trim();
    newGameHistory.historyAdded = div.SelectSingleNode("//span[starts-with(@style, 'white')]").InnerText.Trim();
    newGameHistory.historyRemoved = div.SelectSingleNode("(//span[starts-with(@style, 'white')])[2]").InnerText.Trim();
    gameHistory.Add(newGameHistory);
}
```

Is saying "I have an *h2* tag. Let me get all of the *i* tags with *a* tags inside of them, and certain *span* tags...nothing to do with the *h2* tag though. And let's just keep on getting the firsts in the entire document." (that is what the double slash means).

You are getting 12 results because that's how many *h2* tags there are.

In any case, even if you were specifically to use an *h2* tag as reference, it doesn't seem to have much to do with the rows, looking at it!

So what you need is to get an XPath that will get each row of the correct table (tables in this case). And then, for each row, your XPath should start with a "." (self), so that you're not going back to the root of the document again.

Also, a couple of games don't have a "Removed" column, so you should handle that as well.

Voila my code:

```
    foreach (var div in htmlDocument.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table[@class='wikitable sortable']/tr[td/i/a]"))
    {
        GameHistory newGameHistory = new GameHistory();
        newGameHistory.historyTitle = div.SelectSingleNode(".//i//a").InnerText.Trim();
        newGameHistory.historyAdded = div.SelectSingleNode(".//span[starts-with(@style, 'white')]").InnerText.Trim();
        newGameHistory.historyRemoved = div.SelectSingleNode("(.//span[starts-with(@style, 'white')])[2]") != null? div.SelectSingleNode("(.//span[starts-with(@style, 'white')])[2]").InnerText.Trim() : string.Empty;
        gameHistory.Add(newGameHistory);
    }
```

TIP: To get the headings, inside the foreach loop (starting from the *tr*), you go up once (..) to go to the *table* tag, and then, to get the h2 which is the tag before *table*, use preceding-sibling.

So the XPath would be `"../preceding-sibling::h2"`. It seems that h2 will capture some other characters though so you have to further refine your XPath.

Comment: Thanks Tyress, works perfectly!  One other thing if possible.  Contained in h2 tags is the title of Xbox 360 or Xbox One, as to differentiate from the two separate lists. How would I incorporate that? It would be fine to have either Xbox 360/One heading on every game or just the once to split the list. Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks Tyress. I finished it of like "../preceding-sibling::h2//span[@id= 'Xbox_One']"